# Am I doing something wrong with my <head> or <script>

Tags: javascript, script-tag

I wanted to know if I was doing something strange with my  tag or  tag.  I have some script, that isn't running properly, but works on JS fiddle.  Here is the code:

```
  <head>
<title>Website</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quicksand" rel="stylesheet">
<script>
(function(){

  var parallax = document.querySelectorAll("#textPlaceOne"),
      speed = -0.5;

  window.onscroll = function(){
    [].slice.call(parallax).forEach(function(el,i){

      var windowYOffset = window.pageYOffset,
          elBackgrounPos = "50% " + (windowYOffset * speed) + "px";

      el.style.backgroundPosition = elBackgrounPos;

    });
  };

})();

</script>
</head>
```

Proably something stupid, but thanks if you help!

Comment: What isn't running properly?

Comment: Why don't u just debug it in Chrome or Firefox?

Comment: @AbhiAndhariya I tried that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write your script tag at the bottom of the page after body tag.

If issue persists, Write `debug;` at the first line of your script and open the page in Chrome. Press f12, chrome will let u dubug the issue.

Comment: Still doesn't show any errors.

Comment: It's because your page has not been loaded, when you are calling script. See answer to the duplicate question.

Comment: I have tried that.  It does not load.

Comment: Try refreshing the page using Ctrl + Shift + R to clear the cache.